# c++ application crashes when doing recursive function

Tags: c++, function, recursion, visual-c++, clr

I have a button named `btnTimeIn` that calls `identifyStaff()` function:

```
public: System::Void btnTimeIn_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
        this->identifyStaff();
}
```

And this my `identifyStaff()` function is checking if the staff/user is identified or not. And If it's not identified, there will be a message box that has an ok button and if the `ok` button was clicked the `identifyStaff()` function will be called again.

```
private: System::Void identifyStaff() {
uint32  flag = 0; // 1:accept or 0:reject
... some code beign skip
flag = 1;

... some code being skip



// accept or if finger print was indentified
     if (flag == 1){
         // Open confirmation form
     }
     else 
     {
        if (MessageBox::Show("Staff unidentified. Please rescan again.",
            "Timestamp", MessageBoxButtons::YesNo,
            MessageBoxIcon::Question) == System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::Yes) {
            this->identifyStaff();
        }
        else {
            // do nothing. Close the MessageBox
        }
     }
}
```

Now this is what I do when I run the app:

> 1. click 'time in' button
> 2. I placed unregistered finger in the biometric
> 3. The message box appears with retry button to retry again.
> 4. I click retry/Ok button in message box
> 5. Place finger in the biometric again (this time, the registered finger)
> 6. The identification was successful and the confirmation form opens.
> 7. I close the confirmation form then the application crashes.

I'm still beginner in c++ and haven't yet studied deeper about recursive function.

So, why am I getting this error/ why does my app crash?

Thank you in advance for sharing your knowledge.

**UPDATE**
I update my code in post to show about the flag variable.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude doesn't seem so from OP's description of events.

Comment: That's what i'm trying to do, an infinite recursion, if it's possible.

Comment: At the bare minimum, you need to provide the crash stack.

Comment: What you're trying to do is maybe not what's happening? If you step through the code line by line in a debugger, stepping into the recursive calls, does it work as you expect it to? Will `identified` ever be set?

Comment: If the OP's description is correct ('confirmation form is shown'), the recursion is likely the red herring. This is why crash stack is quintessential.

Comment: And *how* and *where* and *when* is `identified` set? Is it in another even-handler? Because from what I can see the standard application event handler will not be running in your code anywhere. The `MessageBox` event handler (when it's open) only handles events for the message box, not for any other window (IIRC). You have, in effect, a busy-loop that does not handle any events.

Comment: Yes, It do infinite recurstion. But when I close the confirmation form, the application crashes.

Comment: I update my post. because i used actually flag variable to indicate if its identified or not.

Comment: `identified` or `flag` is irrelevant. If it's modified by an event handler, and that event handler never runs, the variable will never change. And I can not press enough on you [learning how to debug your code](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). It's imperative in cases like this, especially since we can not do it for you.

Comment: Why not use a while loop instead of using recursion?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the condition to your recursive function is never set to true and you end up with stack overflow exeption. You've never modified the `identified` variable inside `identifyStaff`.